# What are "T Google Enrolment" and "X Google Enrolment"

Tags: system-apps, google-pixel-3-xl

In my Pixel 3 with stock ROM I can see (among other) apps called "T Google Enrolment" and "X Google Enrolment".  What are these and what do they do? Can I safely disable them?

**UPDATE:** If, as alluded in an answer, these are listening for "OK Google" phrase, why are there two of them and how are they different from "OK Google enrolment"?

Answer (score 1):

To disable it:

1. Open Settings
2. Search for "OK Google"
3. Choose "OK Google Enrolment"
4. Select info
5. Push the "Force stop" button
6. Push the "Disable" button

Comment: This doesn't exactly address the question. Is it safe to remove?

Answer (score 0):

They're used for hotword detection, e.g. continuously listening for "OK Google".

Comment: Thanks.  This only raises more questions: why are there two of them?  And why are they needed in addition to "OK Google enrolment"?